Is the Gemara's story about the oil miracle really included in Megillas Taanis?
B Shab 21b famously records the miracle of the oil (which goes unmentioned in Al HaNissim, Maccabees and Josephus).
It seems to be recorded in both Megillos Taanis & Antiochus.
However, if one reads on further in Megillas Taanis, it queries where the 8 day duration of Chanukah comes from, answering that it derives from how long it took to fix up the Mizbeiach and other utensils, seemingly ignoring the oil miracle that it had just mentioned as the reason for the 8 day duration (yes, barring that it is asking the Beis Yosef's well known question).
Does anyone know if the Megillas Taanis manuscript(s), if extant, contain the oil story?

Don't confuse the main text of MT with its scholion

https://www.jstor.org/stable/23564958

@Joel, The claims being discussed in that article actually strengthen R Miller's explanation that the miracle of the oil was not mentioned in non-Talmudic sources because of the influence of Hellenists and Tzedukim
